# Warning: move_uploaded_file(**Path**): failed to open stream: Permission denied in

Tags: php, file-upload

Hey i alaways get the error

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(**Path**): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in /Users/Shared/xampp-htdocs/php-reports/upload.php on line 27

my index.php code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="datei" accept=".csv"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Hochladen">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my php code is

```
<?php
$upload_folder = getcwd().'/uploads/files'; //Das Upload-Verzeichnis
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


//Überprüfung der Dateiendung
$allowed_extensions = array('csv');
if(!in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {
  die("Ungültige Dateiendung. Nur csv-Dateien sind erlaubt");
}


//Pfad zum Upload
$new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'.'.$extension;

//Neuer Dateiname falls die Datei bereits existiert
if(file_exists($new_path)) { //Falls Datei existiert, hänge eine Zahl an den Dateinamen
  $id = 1;
  do {
    $new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'_'.$id.'.'.$extension;
    $id++;
  } while(file_exists($new_path));
}

//Alles okay, verschiebe Datei an neuen Pfad
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], $new_path);
echo 'Datei erfolgreich hochgeladen: <a href="'.$new_path.'">'.$new_path.'</a>';
?>
```

i also set the directory to chmod 777

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   279 31 Mär 12:00 .htaccess
drwxrwxrwx  2 user  staff    68 31 Mär 11:56 files
```

Comment: Make sure your destination have permission to `777`

Comment: @Saty the directory "files" has permisson to 777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should check who is the apache user because chmod is not sufficient  try to do this in terminal $ ps aux | egrep 'lampp' then you will get the apache user which is the only user having right to upload files into that folder and then change the owner of that foder to this user by typing chown -R "your apache user here in my cas is daemon" /Users/Shared/xampp-htdocs/php-reports/

Comment: thanks man! i also had to switch to the admin accoutn. to change the owner. but now it works !! can you tell me why?

Comment: in major linux ditsro they don't allow user ,  group or other to do some dangerous action like upload or mkdik or rmdir ... because of that they need to be switched to the super user and owning the root folder that you need to  do actions in . hope it was helpful